# Python iteratively create filter expression using items in list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

I'd like to create filter expressions using all items in a list so that I can query a pandas dataframe.

Please use the example code below:

```
col = ['A','B']
data = [[0,5],[3,2],[1,9],[2,7]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=col)

fltr = [('A', 1),
 ('A', 1, 'B', 5)]
```

I'd like to rewrite the code below in a loop so that I don't need to write every possible combination myself:

```
f = ['{0}>={1}'.format(fltr[0][0], fltr[0][1])]
df.query(f)
f = ['{0}<={1}'.format(fltr[0][0], fltr[0][1])]
df.query(f)
f = ['{0}>={1} and {2}>={3}'.format(fltr[1][0], fltr[1][1], fltr[1][2], fltr[1][3])]
df.query(f)
...
```

Also note that I'd like to query every combination of '>=' and '<=' for each expression

Desired expressions:

```
A>=1, A<=1, A>=1 and B>=5, A>=1 and B<=5, A<=1 and B>=5, A<=1 and B<=5
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: With the little information given, it seems that you are seeking to make a pandas dataframe query: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need several parts to get the result you want.  You need a function to split your tuples into series of 2-tuples.  The `product` function from the `itertools` package can handle creating the combinations of column, operation, and value.  You can then `groupby` the column, and use `product` again to get all of the filter combinations.  After that you can merge the strings using `.join` and pass the filters to `df.eval` or `df.query`.

```py
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product, groupby

ge, le = '>=', '<='

def split_tuple(tup):
    return [tup[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(tup), 2)]

def create_basic_filters(tup):
    f_gen = product(split_tuple(tup), (ge, le))
    return [f'{col}{op}{v}' for (col, v), op in f_gen]

def create_filter_groups(basic_filters):
    gb = groupby(basic_filters, key=lambda x: x[:x.find('=')-1])
    groupings = [tuple(g) for _, g in gb]
    return [' & '.join(f) for f in product(*groupings)]


# test the filter creation
fltr = [('A', 1), ('A', 2, 'B', 3), ('A', 1, 'B', 5, 'C', 7), 
        ('A', 0, 'B', 2, 'C', 10, 'D', 15)]

basic_filters = create_basic_filters(fltr[2])
filter_strs = create_filter_groups(basic_filters)
filter_strs
# returns:
['A>=1 & B>=5 & C>=7',
 'A>=1 & B>=5 & C<=7',
 'A>=1 & B<=5 & C>=7',
 'A>=1 & B<=5 & C<=7',
 'A<=1 & B>=5 & C>=7',
 'A<=1 & B>=5 & C<=7',
 'A<=1 & B<=5 & C>=7',
 'A<=1 & B<=5 & C<=7']
```

To actually use the filter we can pass them to `df.eval` to get a boolean Series, or to `df.query` if you want to also slice the data frame.  Below we print the resulting slice of each data frame using a for-loop.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 3, 1, 2],
                   'B': [5, 2, 9, 5],
                   'C': [3, 7, 11, 5],
                   'D': [12, 21, 13, 19]})

for f in filter_strs:
    print('='*30)
    print('Filter =', f)
    print(df.query(f))

# prints:
==============================
Filter = A>=1 & B>=5 & C>=7
   A  B   C   D
2  1  9  11  13
==============================
Filter = A>=1 & B>=5 & C<=7
   A  B  C   D
3  2  5  5  19
==============================
Filter = A>=1 & B<=5 & C>=7
   A  B  C   D
1  3  2  7  21
==============================
Filter = A>=1 & B<=5 & C<=7
   A  B  C   D
1  3  2  7  21
3  2  5  5  19
==============================
Filter = A<=1 & B>=5 & C>=7
   A  B   C   D
2  1  9  11  13
==============================
Filter = A<=1 & B>=5 & C<=7
   A  B  C   D
0  0  5  3  12
==============================
Filter = A<=1 & B<=5 & C>=7
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, C, D]
Index: []
==============================
Filter = A<=1 & B<=5 & C<=7
   A  B  C   D
0  0  5  3  12
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.